# How can we have more than one sequence in a set?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am looking at a proof for a divergence criterion for functional limits:

Let $f$ be a function defined on $A$, and let $c$ be a limit point of $A$. If there exist two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $A$ with $x_n \neq c$ and $y_n \neq c$ and $\lim x_n= \lim y_n=c$ but $\lim f(x_n)= \lim f(y_n)$,then we can conclude that the functional limit $\lim_{x→ c}f(c)$does not exist.

Okay, now that that is out of the way, and I might just be getting terminilogy mixed up, but
say we take the set $A$ to be $[1,10] \in \mathbb{N}  $

Thus isn't the only sequence $1,...,10$ ? and any other combination just a subsequence?

Is a Sub-sequence considered a "sequence" in this definition for divergence?

Comment: What do you mean with $x_n=c$? Just a constant sequence? Also, I think you wrote some $=$ instead of $\not=$ in some places

Comment: @user2520938 sorry - fixed typo

Comment: $[1,10]\notin\mathbb N$

Comment: Is $[1,10] \in \mathbb{N}$ not a way to state the set $\{1,2,3,...,10\}$ ?

Comment: @wahtsgood $[1,10]$ is mostly understood to be an interval in the real numbers, not in the whole numbers. You could write $\{1,2,...,10\}$ to denote the set, or if you want to be a bit more fancy you could write $[1,10]\cap\mathbb{N}$

Comment: got it, thanks!

Comment: @wahtsgood Also, as a last note: $\in$ is placed between an element of a set and the set, for example $5\in \{1,2,...,10\}$. So in your writing of $[1,10]\in\mathbb{N}$ you should have written either $\{1,2,...,10\}\subset\mathbb{N}$, or just $\{1,2,...,10\}$ (since it is clear that $\{1,2,...,10\}\subset\mathbb{N}$ there's no need to specify the $\subset\mathbb{N}$ part). But in any case $[1,10]\in\mathbb{N}$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence:

1. is ordered, meaning that it matters in which order the elements occur
2. can contain elements multiple times

So a sequence in the set $A$ might be

$$(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,....)$$

Or

$$(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,....)$$

Or

$$(1,1,1,1,1,1,.....)$$

But also just

$$(1)$$

Or

$$(1,5,10)$$

And yes a subsequence is always by definition also a sequence.

Comment: Thanks, this clears everything up.

Comment: (+1), but note that in the OP's context, a sequence is _infinite_, i.e., is a function from the natural numbers (or some countable, well-ordered set with a smallest element...) into $A$. That is, only your first three examples are sequences. :)